# Understanding a proof that the sequence of rational approximations of $\sqrt{2}$ is Cauchy but not convergent

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I understand at an intuitive, informal level that the sequence of rational approximations of $\sqrt{2}$ is Cauchy but not convergent. The informal proof is something like this. (I'm using the Euclidean metric for simplicity.)

> Let $p_n = (1, 1.4, 1.41, 1.414, \ldots)$ be the sequence of rational approximations (via truncated decimal expansions) of $\sqrt{2}$. By construction, $p_n \to \sqrt{2} \not \in \mathbb{Q}$ when regarded as a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$, so it is Cauchy in $\mathbb{R}$ and hence in $\mathbb{Q}$ (as the $\epsilon$-$N$ definitions of Cauchy exactly align in $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$). If $p_n$ converged as well to some $q \in \mathbb{Q}$, then it would simultaneously convergence to $q$ and $\sqrt{2}$ when regarded as a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$, contradicting uniqueness of limits in $\mathbb{R}$. So $p_n$ is Cauchy in $\mathbb{Q}$ but fails to converge in $\mathbb{Q}$.

I'm reading and trying to understand a formalization of this argument. I'm going to try to paraphrase the argument, pausing at steps I don't understand.

> Define $x_n := \frac{d_n}{10^n}$ where for each $n$, $d_n$ is defined as the largest natural number such that $\left(\frac{d_n}{10^n}\right)^2 < 2$.

This definition doesn't make sense to me at all or even how we know for a fact that there *is* a great such natural number. I know that the intention is to take the $n$th digit after the decimal point in the decimal expansion of $\sqrt{2}$, but I don't understand exactly how this definition accomplishes that.

> We claim that $x_n$ is Cauchy. Given $\epsilon > 0$, choose $N \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $\frac{1}{10^N} < \epsilon$.

I think I'm ok with this, even without proving that such an $N$ existed. If I wanted to find exact conditions on such an $N$, I could argue:
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{10^N} < \epsilon & \iff 10^N > \frac{1}{\epsilon} \\
& \iff N \log 10 = \log 10^N > \log \frac{1}{\epsilon} = - \log \epsilon \\ 
& \iff N > - \frac{\log \epsilon}{\log 10}. 
\end{align*}

Returning to the proof:

> Suppose $m,n \geq N + 1$. Then, because $x_m$ and $x_n$ agree up to the $(N+1)$st decimal place, $|x_m - x_n| \leq \frac{1}{10^N} < \epsilon$.

I think this is taking the overarching index in the definition of Cauchy, which we usually call $N$, to be $N+1$, which makes sense. The remainder of the argument hinges on the definition of $x_n$, which I still don't fully understand, so I don't fully see how the inequality comes together.

I'd appreciate any help on understanding this problem.

Comment: It might help to look at concrete examples of $d_n$.  eg take $n=1$. You'll find for $x = 0, 1, 2, ..., 14$ we have $(x/10)^2 < 2$, while for $x = 15$ $(x/10)^2 > 2$.  So, $14/10 = 1.4$ give the first 2 decimals of $\sqrt{2}$.  Do you see why that works?

Comment: For justifying the existence of $d_n$, let $S = \{x  \in \mathbb{N} | (x/10^n)^2 < 2\}$. Then we want to take the max of $S$.  We can always do this as long as $S$ is finite and nonempty. To show $S$ is finite, note that if $x \geq 2 \cdot 10^n$ then $(x/10^n)^2 \geq 4$ and so $x \notin S$, so that all $x\in S$ satisfy $x < 2 \cdot 10^n$. To see $S$ is nonempty, note $0 \in S$ (assuming a definition where $0 \in \mathbb{N}$).